# Alternative with Either

Tags: scala

I'd like to use `alternative` with `Either[A, B]` in Scala.

Here's what I came up with:

```
scala> val x: Either[String, Int] = Left("Foo")
x: Either[String,Int] = Left(Foo)

scala> val y: Either[String, Int] = Right(5555)
y: Either[String,Int] = Right(5555)

scala> x.fold(_ => y, _ => x)
res1: Either[String,Int] = Right(5555)
```

Is this the idiomatic approach when using the standard library only?

My concern is that I'll have quite the number of `fold`'s as I use more than 2 `Either`'s.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to acomplish but `x.left.flatMap(_ => y)` seems equivalent, not sure if it satisfies you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with some pimping:

```
implicit class EitherOps[A,B] (x: Either[A,B]) {
  def orElse (y: => Either[A,B]) = x.fold(_ => y, _ => x)
}
x orElse y orElse z
```

Keep in mind, it is discarding all the possible `Left`s except for the last one (as your sample code does too).

(updated: with pass-by-name as suggested by Odomontois in the comment)

Comment: It's more idiomatic to use pass-by-name arguments in methods like this since `y` value is not always used.

Comment: @Odomontois - would you consider using `Function0[Either[A,B]]` rather than `pass-by-name`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Wouldn't that mean you would have to do: `x orElse (() => y) orElse (() => z)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this, which takes any number of `Either[]` args. Type information is retained only if all the arguments conform to the same type profile.

```
def firstRight[A,B](args:Either[A,B]*):Either[A,B] = args match {
  case Right(x)     +: _    => Right(x)
  case Seq(Left(x))         => Left(x)
  case _            +: tail => firstRight(tail: _*)
}
```

Comment: IMO it have unneeded loss of type information. Probably `Either[A,B]` would be more practical result type.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about it I agree.  I've modified it accordingly.